# How to schedule an update?

Tags: 10.10, updates, cron

I want to schedule my machine to run all my updates unattended at night, but this requires my authentication (which pretty much axes the unattended part). Would it be best to use a cron job or is there something better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out `cron-apt`. It can do exactly that. I use `cron-apt` to download packages and send email that tells what can be updated.

If you are running anything critical (not your own desktop computer, that is), automatically installing updates is risky.

- Something breaks (for example some software removes some configuration parameter you were using, and it's not starting anymore; that's why something important was down for several hours / you were paged in the middle of night).
- Your server do not boot after it upgraded *something*. You reboot it several days later, and you have no idea what went wrong (of course, you can fix this by sending out those update report emails).

If you perform attended update (meaning you are sitting somewhere during your computer actually installs new packages), you can fix problems immediately, not in the morning, when everything has been broken for several hours already. Or alternatively, you'll wake up when your excellent monitoring system alarms that important things are not working.

Comment: @Olli Do you mean cron-apt?

Comment: In more than 5 years i never received an update which I didn't install - to what information would I refuse that? So why not let it automatically happen? I guess the risk is very low.

Comment: @Reuben Swartz: of course, thank you. I updated my answer.

Comment: @user unknown: in more than 5 years I have received multiple updates that broke something, and required manual intervention. Including mysql, apache2, and LDAP libraries. With Ubuntu LTS and with Debian, for example. Also, few times there have been dependency which removed important package(s). Therefore, I would claim running unattended updates during night is risky.

Comment: If those updates broke something - how did you knew it before? Why were they rolled out, while it was public, that they will brake something? Or did it actually break, and why is it better to break at daylight attended, instead of nightly?

Comment: @user unknown: well, well. There is huge number of different configurations (in addition to weird configurations). It's impossible to test all of those. That's why there is updates that break things (also, some projects do not handle QA that well). Let's state obvious: usually it's better to fix something immediately (attended install) instead of installing something automatically and then waiting several hours, and fixing it in the morning. When you come to work in the morning and server is not booting because new kernel isn't working with RAID controller? That's so nice.

Comment: So either you arrive at work, and RAID controller isn't working, or you arrive at work, install updates and the RAID controller isn't working; did I get that right? You wouldn't call the server at work 'your machine', would you? However - if it is important that the machine worked from 01:00 to 09:00, I guess Reuben would have mentioned that, or would not have came up with that idea at all.